# why I have this error bash ng command not found while I already installed the angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular, bash, command-line-interface, angular-cli

my problem is that after installing angular CLI and started working with angular something happened and the ng command became not found command:

```
ng serve -o
```

please check this picture:
[bash: ng: command not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XStsw.png)

but when I write it with the npx command it works:

```
npx ng serve -o
```

does anyone knows why?

Comment: There is no executable program named `ng` in any of the directories listed in the $PATH variable.

Comment: It is the angular command and I am using it to run an angular command in a project, as I said with the npx the command is running normally but without it it is not working, while it was working at the beginning,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that Angular is globally installed in your machine? If no; try this :

> npm install -g @angular/cli

if yes; the problem can be due to the reason that npm is unable to find ng command, you can try linking the angular/cli to npm like this :

> npm link @angular/cli

Comment: I already installed it and I just tried to link it but nothing changed, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

1. first install Homebrew ( https://brew.sh/ ) (if you  already have installed, skip this step )

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Install angular-cli ( https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/angular-cli )

```
brew install angular-cli
```

3. Please check that it works now.

```
ng --version
```

4. If it is still not working or if there is a warning.

> "command not found: ng" or "angular-cli [version-no] is already installed, it's just not linked."

run this common

```
brew link angular-cli
```

then check it again, this works for me.